# Perhaps similar number theory problems

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have this question:

> $n \in \Bbb N$. $n \geq 3$. Prove that $$ 1989\mid  n^{n^{n^n}} - n^{n^n}$$

and also this question:

> Find the last five digits of $5^{5^{5^5}}$.

What I saw that $1989 =9 \times 13 \times 17$ and tried to show that the numbers  $9$, $13$ and $17$ separately divide  $n^{n^{n^n}} - n^{n^n}$. But, it is of the form $n^t-t$ and so I cannot apply Fermat's or Euler's theorem. Also, I cannot think of suitable factorisations and I'm stuck. For the second one, the last digit is $5$, but what about the rest? I think these two problems may have a similar solution and so I posted them together.

Comment: Have you tried showing $n^{n^{n^{n}}} \equiv n^{n^{n}}\mod(1989)$?

Comment: I don't know where to start on that, @gregkow.

Comment: I have no idea how to approach this, but wow! The first result seems amazing to me!

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=527693&p=2998058&hilit=1989#p2998058

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both problems, you should use the following corollary of Euler's theorem: if $\gcd(a,q)=1$ and $j\equiv k\pmod{\phi(q)}$, then $a^j\equiv a^k\pmod q$.

For example, finding the last five digits of $5^{5^{5^5}}$ is equivalent to calculating the least positive residue of $5^{5^{5^5}}\pmod{10^5}$. But by the corollary, you only need to know $5^{5^5}$ modulo $\phi(10^5) = 4\cdot 10^4$. And so on....

For the first problem, to show $17$ divides $n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}$, consider both $n^{n^n}$ and $n^n$ modulo $\phi(17)=16$, and so on....